# How to fix a function inorder to get the right count

Tags: python, pandas

Basis on the category i want to create a new category by using a function. However when I built a function, it is not getting the right counts. I have created a sample data for reference. Please find below the code:

## creating a dataframe for reference

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "vendor":    [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    "overdue":  ["yes", "no",   "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no"],
    "category": ["high",    "medium",   "Low",  "others",   "medium",   "Low",  "Low",  "others",   "high", "medium",   "Low",  "others",   "medium",   "Low",  "others"]
})
```

### Getting the counts

```
df['category'].value_counts()
```

##Using functions to adjust the category

```
def newcat(x,y):
    if x=="high":
        return "High_Risky"
    elif x=="medium" and y=="yes":
        return "Medium_Risky"
    elif x=="Low" and x=="others":
        return "Low_Risky"

df['overdue_flag']=df.apply(lambda x:newcat(x['category'],x['overdue']),axis=1)
```

Comment: What are you doing with the results of `df['category'].value_counts()` and what do you expect your resulting `df` to look like?

Comment: What should be the result when category is `medium` and overdue `no` ?

Comment: Aside: your last `elif` statement will always be false as `x` cannot both be `== "low"` and `== "others"`.

Comment: i would like to replace High as High_Risky,Low and Others as Low_risky, Medium as Medium risky and where Overdue='Yes' as Medium_risky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "vendor":    [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    "overdue":  ["yes", "no",   "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no"],
    "category": ["high",    "medium",   "Low",  "others",   "medium",   "Low",  "Low",  "others",   "high", "medium",   "Low",  "others",   "medium",   "Low",  "others"]
})

def new_cat(df):
    # Create new column 'overdue_flag' with default value 'Low_Risky'
    df.loc[:, 'overdue_flag'] = 'Low_Risky'

    # Apply first condition
    mask1 = df['category'] == "high"
    df.loc[mask1, 'overdue_flag'] = "High_Risky"

    # Apply second condition
    mask2 = (df['category'] == "medium") & (df['overdue'] == "yes")
    df.loc[mask2, 'overdue_flag'] = "Medium_Risky"

    return df

df = new_cat(df)
print(df)

# Outputs
    vendor overdue category  overdue_flag
0        1     yes     high    High_Risky
1        2      no   medium     Low_Risky
2        3     yes      Low     Low_Risky
3        4      no   others     Low_Risky
4        5     yes   medium  Medium_Risky
5        6      no      Low     Low_Risky
6        7     yes      Low     Low_Risky
7        8      no   others     Low_Risky
8        9      no     high    High_Risky
9       10     yes   medium  Medium_Risky
10      11      no      Low     Low_Risky
11      12      no   others     Low_Risky
12      13      no   medium     Low_Risky
13      14     yes      Low     Low_Risky
14      15      no   others     Low_Risky
```

Comment: I don't get any error on my part, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you've multiple `if/else` conditions, use `np.select` `(vectorized/fast)` just provide the conditions in `condlist` and what to do with that particular condition in `choicelist` -

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [
    (df['category'] == "medium") & (df['overdue'] == "yes"),
    (df['category'] == "high")
]

choicelist = [
    'High_Risky',
    'Medium_Risky'
]


df['overdue_flag'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
```